# Images in public folder not found after each push on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am having issues with my Rails App on Heroku.

After every push to heroku any images I uploaded with paperclip Gem return a 404 error message.
How I resolve this?

Comment: You should be uploading your assets to an external server, like Amazon S3.

Comment: No, that's what you should be doing.

Comment: There is, or at least was recently, a way. If your asset files are not huge, you can deploy them as other regular app files. Keep in mind, any assets update need to be reflected again to Heroku's instance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the local file system on Heroku to store uploaded files, because you get a new instance each time you deploy. I advise to read about [Ephemeral filesystem on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

To fix your problem you show store uploaded files on an external service like Amazon S3. You might want to follow [Heroku's documentation about uploading to S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)